# using .then for ajax call wrapped in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below code

```js
function fetchInfo(tableName, tableFields) {
  $.ajax({
    url: `${baseUrl}/_api/getTableData('${tableName}')/details?$tableFieldsQueried=${tableFields.join(',')}`,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function success(res) {
      return res
    },
    eror: function eror(err) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  })
}

fetchInfo("test1", ["tfield", "sfield"])
fetchInfo("test2", ["qfield", "rfield"])
fetchInfo("test3", ["ttfield", "dfield"])
```

If i use

```
fetchInfo("test4", ["efield","hfield"]).then((res) => console.log(res))
```

i am not getting because chaining should be done to the ajax call, so how can i use the same function to fetch data using ajax call.

Is there any way or do i need to have same ajax code to be repeated 4 times for each call

Comment: `return $.ajax({ ...`

Comment: thank  you it worked :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan $.ajax returns Promise?

Comment: No, a `jqXHR` object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so how we can use .then on a ajax response is there any method is there?

Comment: The important fact in this case is that `$.ajax` returns a *thenable*

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i thought wrapping inside a `new Promise` object works. and resolve the result after.

Comment: so the above way of coding is proper or not the best practice

Comment: also i have the data in res.data but when i  am returning it , i am getting res not res.data like  
success: function success(res) {
      return res.data
    }

but fetchInfo("sa", ["a", "b"]).then(res => console.log(res)) // i am getting res not res.data

Comment: @zabusa sure you could do that too, but it's redundant as `$.ajax()` will be doing that for you anyway

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS The method you're using now is absolutely fine and the most succinct method to achieve what you need. Although you're stating that `.then()` doesn't receive data - which is correct. This is by design.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan also i have the data in res.data but when i am returning it , i am getting res not res.data like success: function success(res) { return res.data } but fetchInfo("sa", ["a", "b"]).then(res => console.log(res)) // i am getting res not res.data

Comment: In that case `then()`  will not work for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171236/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-rory-mccrossan).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if he using the `.then` the that success and error callback can be removed? the result anyways delegate to the then(res) so no need to write the callbacks?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so whats the best way to retrieve data if my actual data is inside the res (response of ajax call)

Comment: @zabusa so i need to remove the success and error callbacks , is that what you are saying

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS i think it will work because anyways then contains the response right? check its works or not.

Comment: @zabusa it worked so if  there is an error , then i need to manage it in .then()

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS. dont know. check the documentation there will be some chaining methods to handle error also.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS instead of using .then you can use .done and .fail in a chainable manner.refer the below documentation.

Comment: @zabusa i tried with done and fail worked properly thank you

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS powliku

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually return [the ajax request object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) from your function.

```
function fetchInfo(tableName, tableFields) {
  return $.ajax({    // <-- Here
    url: `${baseUrl}/_api/getTableData('${tableName}')/details?$tableFieldsQueried=${tableFields.join(',')}`,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function success(res) {
      return res
    },
    eror: function eror(err) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for Rory McCrossan , i forgot it, You need to return the ajax call

```
function fetchInfo(tableName, tableFields) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: `${baseUrl}/_api/getTableData('${tableName}')/details?$tableFieldsQueried=${tableFields.join(',')}`,
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function success(res) {
      return res
    },
    eror: function eror(err) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  })
}

fetchInfo("test4", ["tfield", "sfield"]).then((res) => console.log(res))
```